# How to properly size the keras dense output layer

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to run a RNN in keras using data from midi files to generate music but I am running into a problem on the last layer of the model where it runs into the error: "Error when checking target: expected dense_26 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (110539,)". Why does the network expect a 1 sized output layer when my labels are of size (110539) and what size should the dense layer be? My code is below:

```
input_data=[np.random.randint(0,110539) for i in range(32427)]
input_temp =[]
output_temp = []
for i in range(0,len(input_data)-seq_length,1):
    input_temp.append(input_data[i:i+seq_length])
    output_temp.append(input_data[i+seq_length])

sequences = len(output_temp)

x = np.reshape(input_temp,(sequences,seq_length,1))
x = x/classes
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(output_temp)
classes = y[0].shape[0]

model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(512,input_shape=(seq_length,1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(512))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(classes,activation='softmax'))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3,decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt)
model.fit(x,y,epochs=3)
```

When I print x.shape I get (32327, 100, 1) and the dimensions of y are (32327, classes). Thanks for any help

edit: The output of model.summary()

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm_1 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 100, 512)          1054720   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100, 512)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_2 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 512)               2101248   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 110539)            28408523  
=================================================================
```

Comment: What is `classes`? Both before and after `classes = y[0].shape[0]`.

Comment: @Jeppe In this example because the data is random the number of classes keeps changing but using the actual data classes is 110539

Comment: @Jeppe My mistake classes should be defined before the line x /= classes

Comment: Yeah this error simply hints to `classes` being equal to 1 when you define the Dense layer. You should also look into using the Keras functional API: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia I'm pretty sure the Dense layer is defined with classes correctly. I have added the output of model.summary() but it looks like dense_2 has the right shape?

Comment: @Jeppe Should the input also be converted to one hot vectors?

Comment: @treutm The labels should, I think.